# Current date parameter in Azure DataFactory

Tags: parameters, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in an Azure DataFactory context. This pipeline has a dataset which is a metadata table and this metadata table needs to be updated regularly. I can update the table using a query in a lookup activity.

The column I need to update contains the date of the last trigger. So, I would like to ask if is there any way of getting the current date as a parameter in the pipeline. If so, I could insert the parameter in my query and update the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with variable in your azure data factory pipeline.

First click the blank space and define a variable with any value as its default value.

[image]

Then add a "Set variable" activity to set the value of the variable. Set its value with `@utcnow()`

[image]

[image]

Then you can use the variable in your pipeline.

By the way, if you want to specify the format of utc now, you can use `utcNow('<format>')`. Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#utcNow).