# How to add a date picker field as a parameter to azure data factory pipelines?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to fetch the list of employees who Date of birth between Jan 1, 1990 to Dec 31, 2000. These date changes rapidly and I want to give the user a date picker field that allows them to choose the date range.

How can I pick the DOB start and the end Date as a parameter in the pipeline and send it to the SQL procedure?

Eg.

```
concat('SELECT emp_name from employees where emp_dob BETWEEN ''',  pipeline().parameters.startDate,''' AND ''',pipeline().parameters.endDate);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want to pick the pipeline parameter values from date picker (or) just give the values to parameters and send them to stored procedure?

Comment: Datepicker. User is going to choose the date and run the pipeline. It should result the list of employees who DOB is within the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

You need to provide it manually. You can check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67865321) resolved by Hury Shen

To give values to pipeline parameters using date picker is not possible.